# mvn clean package does not work, missing project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm going through this tutorial: http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/java/spring-boot/create-spring-boot-application-step-step/

And I have maven installed, and I went to run **mvn clean package** 
in the directory **\SpringBoot\src\main\java\com\adeveloperdiary** but it keeps saying

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------     ---
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.059 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-07T11:45:06-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no   POM in this directory   (C:\Users\kbultman\Downloads\SpringBoot\src\main\java\com\adeveloperdiary).   Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

This is my mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\kbultman\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "windows
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to run the maven command in the top level directory of the project. To do that you need to use the "cd" command like so:

> cd \path\to\directory

In your case the directory would probably be

> C:\Users\kbultman\Downloads\SpringBoot

instead of

> C:\Users\kbultman\Downloads\SpringBoot\src\main\java\com\adeveloperdiary

Comment: That didn't work - it starts building snapshot- but now it states this error: BUILD FAILURE [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project SpringBoot: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8

Comment: That means you are now at least running the maven command in the proper directory. You seem to have a JDK that is incompatible with the project. You probably need Oracle JDK 8 that you can get from here [jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: The right way to do this on StackOverflow would be to accept my answer as correct since it did solve your initial error and maybe post another question with the new error. That way, me or somebody can help offer further help with it.

Comment: I have JDK 8- java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Like I said, you should create a new question with that error. We would need to see the pom.xml file and the full output of the command that fails.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Ping me if/when you create a new question, maybe I can help.